# How To make Preg_Match or PATTERN

Tags: php

I have a url and i want it pattern or preg_match function 
url looks like this

```
http://www.myurl.com/login/login.php?confirmation=1&sub=a18c6aff-614c-49b2-ab67-5d90f839dce6-299072-1
```

i am going to run with loop and every time i am getting a different url but i need only the last value

> a18c6aff-614c-49b2-ab67-5d90f839dce6-299072-1

i tried every process that i know for preg_match but i failed

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, its always the last value, so you can `explode()` and get the last value using `end()`:

**Code:**

```
$str = 'http://www.myurl.com/login/login.php?confirmation=1&sub=a18c6aff-614c-49b2-ab67-5d90f839dce6-299072-1
';
$newStr = explode('=', $str);
echo end($newStr);
```

**Output:**

```
a18c6aff-614c-49b2-ab67-5d90f839dce6-299072-1
```

Comment: i have again second problem i need to run that value with another url then how could i put with in

Comment: i try below method   $new="https:// myurl.com/id=end(newstr)";   but i get error like in print it show array

Comment: thank you once again dear bro rally helpful for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help! You are accept/approve this answer. Happy Coding!